# Wrapping image shadows to border around texts

Tags: html, css

Before:
[image: Before]

After:
[image: After]

Using the following two images:
[image: Using this]

[image: And this]

My HTML:

```
<table class=full>
<tr>
<td class=showTemp2>
THE INFORMATION GOES HERE<br><br>
WRAPPED AROUND THE TWO SHADOW IMAGES<br><br>
AND WE ARE DONE
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

My CSS:

```
.full {
width: 900px;
}
.showTemp2 {
    color: #1D2F9F;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: Verdana, 'Source Sans Pro';
    font-weight: plain;
    width: 100%;
}
```

What I am looking to accomplish is the **After** image but I can't seem to accomplish it with the CSS I have in place. I want the images to stretch out and wrap the texts based on the width of the "full" table.

**SOLUTION**:

```
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
```

Comment: Why not use CSS for the shadow?

Comment: `box-shadow` is usable with IE >= 9; if you're not needing to support older IE's than that, you should consider using that.

Comment: Our entire place is currently using IE 8, so I am just considering using the images for now. And use the box-shadow as an alternative for IE 9 and newer.

Comment: Even if you have to support older IEs, I'd still suggest going for that. Then give older IEs a simple border.

Comment: box-shadow gives only border around right and bottom

Comment: That doesn't look like tabular data.  There is a way this could be done in IE8, but the fact that you're using a table complicates it.

Comment: Please look at my SOLUTION i posted, it works fine in FF but there is nothing in IE 8.

Comment: Looking at your images : Is this homework ?

Comment: Actually i decided to do away with images and rely on CSS :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use an image... you can try and use 3 images...

1st image for top part...
2nd image to be repeated in y-axis (this will extend with the length of your content)
3rd image for bottom part...

```
<table class=full>
<tr>
<td class="topPart"></td>
<td class="middlepart">
THE INFORMATION GOES HERE<br><br>
WRAPPED AROUND THE TWO SHADOW IMAGES<br><br>
AND WE ARE DONE
</td>
<td class="lastPart"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This will also be more flexible than using only two images...

Comment: If not can you put your files in jsfiddle. I'll try. :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FRRXc/ (this works fine in FF/Chrome but I do not see anything in IE8)

Comment: fiddle does not work too good with IE. It is all broken down. Did you fix it? If not, just taking a wild idea here... try putting overflow: hidden; May sound stupid.. but sometime it fixes odd things.

F^%# IE!!!

Comment: Sadly Yes i figured. I was testing it out on my website. That's why I was able to say it doesnt work on IE 8

Comment: If you can give your site address... can have a look at that...

there should be a solution  :)

Answer (score 1):

This would be how to use 2 images, work in IE8, and not use unnecessary markup.  However, your images will need modification as they are not the same width.

http://cssdeck.com/labs/e3vpdl4a

```
<p class=full>
THE INFORMATION GOES HERE<br><br>
WRAPPED AROUND THE TWO SHADOW IMAGES<br><br>
AND WE ARE DONE
</p>

.full {
  width: 850px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.full:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  height: 172px;
  width: 100%;
  top: -40px;
  left: -20px;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMU3n.png) no-repeat;  
}

.full:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  height: 172px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: -40px;
  left: -20px;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHtDh.png) left bottom no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Good plan.  Using images this way tends to be inflexible.

Comment: Plus why waste extra bandwidth, although it's not a lot but it adds up to load the page. The css I posted in my question works fine in FF/Chrome/IE>=9

Answer (score 1):

```
.box-shadow{
    -o-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    /* IE */
    *zoom:1;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#aaaaaa,direction=135,strength=10);
}
```

IE less than 9 do not support cssLevel3, you will have to use microsoft filters.

Otherwise, you will have to split your texture in 3 parts, left-centerBottom-right, then redesign you html to texture your element from inside a container (like from cimmanon suggestion).

For the 'msFilter' explanation, i took my tests from here : http://hedgerwow.appspot.com/demo/shadow

Comment: When i used your code, it put shadow on the texts itself. Hmmm not sure why it's putting shadows on the texts instead of the DIV.

Comment: Heres the JDFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ZXD3r/ (for some reason its not working in IE <= 8)

Comment: jsFiddle is NOT (InternetExplorer < 9) friendly.

Comment: Yes. I was testing it out on my website. That's why I was able to say it doesnt work on IE 8.